# Disable backward navigation when pressing backspace, allow backspace in fields

Tags: javascript

How can I modify this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
</script>
```

To allow the user to backspace in form fields on a page, but prevent them from navigating backwards by mistake?

Comment: usually you try to see where the focus is => `event.currentTarget` or `event.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the `current.target` to see if it's an input or not:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which,
        nodeName = event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    if (key === 8 && nodeName !== 'input') {
        alert('that\'s a nono');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Also note the `event.which` to support older browsers. But that's completely up to you of course.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/z0q7L2o8/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also add other input fields like "textarea", "div", etc. depending on your requirements.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
        nodeName = event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    if ( (event.keyCode === 8 || event.which=== 8 ) && nodeName !== 'input') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```